# Is it safe to send parameter in http header

Tags: http, http-headers

As i know, when client send http request to server, for safety reason we should not send secret param on request url.

A lot of people say we should use body to attach parameter, i do agree

But what if i use header to send them? Is it safe like body? Somebody say it is not safe like body but could not explain why, please help

Thank

Comment: use https instead of http. most API are authorized by header keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open debug console in your browser and you will see there are no difference. From TCP perspective, all the request is just a text file with few new lines between headers and body. And once you send requests over not encrypted channel (http), everything can be captured by the man in the middle. No safe place. On hte other hand, if you use **https**, your connection is encrypted (on lower level - TCP) and both body and headers are safe enough to transsmit sensitive information. The only "wrong" place even on https is URL, as someone behind your shoulder can see your secrets in browser's address bar.

Comment: Exactly. Cookies are sent in headers and, while they have many problems, being in the header instead of the body is not one of them.